# Lumen session not working

Tags: session, authentication, lumen

I have a simple auth system described [here](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/authentication)

I have `Auth::attempt` working in order to check if credentials of users are ok or not. And I get back the user from `Auth::user()`.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password),true)) {
    // everything is fine and user is logged
    return view('login', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
}
```

Then if I try a `Auth::check()` in another controller, it always return **`false`**.

I discovered that my session are not working. Simple things like put or get described [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#session-drivers%20are%20not%20working).

So how can I activate session used by lumen ?

I'm using nginx + php-fpm.

I have no errors on `nginx/error.log` or `lumen.log`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `bootstrap/app.php`, make sure you have un-commented these lines:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

$app->middleware([
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
]);
```

Comment: Thanks you. The middleware was empty ... Now I have a TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46 even after clearing client cookies.

Comment: Probably you forget CSRF token input in your form. Read this documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security

Comment: Yes, my token was empty and from your link I just added <?php echo csrf_token(); ?> inside the value attribute like in the documentation. It works thanks :)